Faster regex to match all worded numbers from 1 to 99
I would like to know if there is a better regex to match all worded numbers from 1 to 99.
With "better" I mean shorter with same performance, OR faster.
I came up with this.  I can't do better.
const regex = /\b(?<!\-)(?:(?:twen(?=ty)|thir|four(?=te)|for(?=ty)|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine)t(?:een|y)(?:(?<=ty)\-(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))?|(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve))/g;
const testString = see_regex101_link
const isMatch = regex.test(testString);
console.log(isMatch);

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/CYBK5S/1
Javascript if possible.

I expect that maintaining a set of 99 strings would be best in terms of execution speed, readability and time required for testing. In Ruby (think pseudo-code), suffixes = ["one", "two", ..., "nine"], prefixes = ["twenty", "thirty", ..., "ninety"], teens = ["ten", "eleven", ..., "nineteen"], cartesian_product = prefixes.product(['-'], suffices).map(&:join) #=> ["twenty-one", "twenty-two", ..., "twenty-nine", "thirty-one", ..., "ninety-nine"],  then create a constant that holds a set of 99 strings: ONE_TO_ONE_HUNDRED = Set[suffices + teens + prefixes + cartesian_product].

I expect REs to get "compiled" into small automatons, with many expressions resulting in the same automaton.

After more testing, I just optimized Jdm(user) solution:
/\b(?:(?:twen|thir|for|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine)ty(?:-(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))?|(?:thir|four|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine)teen|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve)\b/
The best regex with Javascript and PCRE2 (didn't test others) when the string has all worded numbers from 1 to 99 equally. Also the most readable.
https://regex101.com/r/JZGYSD/1
You can optimize it based on context:

if most of the numbers are > 20, the regex above is better.
if they < 20, move 1-9 to first
/\b(?:(?<![efhnrx]ty-)(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)|(?:twen|thir|for|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine)ty(?:\-(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))?|(?:thir|four|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine)teen|ten|eleven|twelve)\b/


Honestly, I got a bit curious of your question and started trying some things.
I have found that your pattern takes on average 0.215ms, which was hard to beat.
However, for some reason the following pattern averages in 0.15ms:
const pattern = /\b(?:twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)(?:-(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine))?|(?:ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen)|(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\b/g

So this pattern might not be shorter but quicker.

"For some reason": I wonder if the nearly-alphabetical sorting of the words helped the regex engine build a pseudo-trie. E.g. there's a lot of t-words, followed by f-words, and s-words, and so on.

I just tested it. Using the benchmark feature both mine and yours have a minimum of 32ms match time. Multiply the string magnitude if your machine is too fast. Despite yours having -20% steps than mine on PCRE2 flavour, i don't see a difference even with jsfiddle.

To detail it, yours is faster on PCRE2, but not with Javascript (test on jsfiddle might be useful)
